# how can I draw a triangle of asterisks using the while statement?

Tags: c#, for-loop, while-loop

here is the (not working code) and it should print the shape below but its not :

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int i = 1;
    int k = 5;
    int h = 1;

    while (i <= 5)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("");
        while (k > i)
        {
            Console.Write(" ");
            k--;
        }
        while (h <= i)
        {
            Console.Write("**");
            h++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    Console.ReadLine();

}
```

[image: Screenshot]

but when I try to do the same using the while statement the shape gets totally messed up.

any help ?

Comment: Show your while code.

Comment: We need to see your not-working code to fix your not-working code, not your working code =)

Comment: How could you get the single aterisk on the top while your code writes double aterisks only?

Comment: Hint: `for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){yourcode;}` is equal to: `int i = 0; while(i < 5){ yourcode; i++ }`

Comment: Pretty important that you also learn what *doesn't* work.  More important, actually, nobody really cares that you got the triangles right.  Asking for help just completely defeats that goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to declare `k` and `h` within the loop:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int i = 1;
    while (i <= 5)
    {
        int k = 5;
        int h = 1;

        Console.WriteLine("");
        while (k > i)
        {
            Console.Write(" ");
            k--;
        }
        while (h <= i)
        {
            Console.Write("**");
            h++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

With your current solution, after first outer loop iteration, inner loops do nothing.

Answer (score 2):

```
int NumberOfLines = 5;
int count = 1;
while (NumberOfLines-- != 0)
{
    int c = count;
    while (c-- != 0)
    {
        Console.Write("*");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
    count = count + 2;
}
```

That's it, simplest implementation.

Comment: Except this is missing the desired spacing of the asterisks.

Answer (score 0):

I'll not solve for you just will give you hint only:
Use 3 loop statements

```
1. for line change
2. for spaces (reverse loop)
3. for printing * (odd series in this case) i.e. 2n-1
```

check in third while statement **h <= 2*i - 1;**
and print only one `*` in place of `**`

**Check here:**
http://ideone.com/xOB2OI

Comment: you should declare `h,k` inside first while loop

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `i`, `k` and `h` are initialised before the outermost loop is entered. Within the outer loop `k` and `h` are altered by the inner loops. On the second execution of the outer loop `k` and `h` have the same values as were left after running the inner loops previously. As `i` increments in the outer loop, the `k` loop will not be entered and the `h` loop will only run once.

Think about what values `h` and `k` should have inside the outermost loop on the second execution.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I've done this via 'for' loop, z is height and x is equal to length of side.

Isosceles triangle (x>z):

```
 public void Print(int x, int z)
        {
            var peakStart = x;
            var peakEnd = x;

            for (int i = 0; i < z; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 2 * x + 1; j++)
                {
                    if (peakStart < 1.5 * x && j >= peakStart && j <= peakEnd)
                        Console.Write("*");
                    else
                        Console.Write(" ");
                }
                peakStart--;
                peakEnd++;
                Console.WriteLine("");
            }
        }
```